# Add container to storage account with deny policy

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a storage account with private access inside a vnet. ultimately I am looking to create a storage account that can only be accessed by a VM inside a particular subnet.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "private" {
  name                = "terraformprivategv11"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  account_kind              = "BlobStorage"
  shared_access_key_enabled = false
  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "tfstate" {
  name                  = "tfstate"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.private.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

With the network rule set to deny, I can no longer create the container. (I realise that this is the point of the deny policy)

Is there a way to do this? I suspect it will need multiple runs to complete. Everything I've done so far feels hacky...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create the storage account with a default action of allow and then change it to deny after container creation, there may be two options.

1. Run the terraform deployment from a VM within the subnet that you are allowing (azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id).
2. Add an IP rule for the public IP address of the system from which you are running the terraform deployment.

```
      network_rules {
        default_action             = "Deny"
        ip_rules                   = ["100.0.0.1"]
        virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
      }
```

Afterwards you could remove the rule again in your config file and re-run the terraform deployment.

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account

You could find your systems public ip address by running `curl ifconfig.co` in a command prompt.